# At the time of speaking, should I use "do", "will", or "would"?

Tags: word-choice, usage, questions, conditional-constructions

Just before I ask a question to someone, what should I have to say?

> Do you mind if I ask you a  question?

> Will you mind if I ask you a  question?

> Would you mind if I ask you a question?

Which one is correct at the time of speaking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first is grammatical can be used on most occasions. The second is also grammatical, but would be used much less frequently, depending on what has previously been said in the conversation. The third is a conditional sentence of the kind in which the verb in the *if*-clause is normally in the past tense. You might hear *Would you mind if I **ask** you a question?* but *Would you mind if I **asked** you a question?* is less likely to raise concerns over its grammaticality. It would be used if the speaker wished to be more tentative about asking a question.

Comment: @snailplane. Probably not. I took care to hedge my answer. Foreign learners will not be in error if they always change the present tense to past tense in such cases, but they might sometimes be if they don't.

Comment: @snailplane, this sounds better “Do you mind if I open the window?” but what you wrote is grammatically correct.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is more polite to say it like this:

> Would you mind if I ask you a question?